# Multi-dimensional Abel transform

Tags: integration

How to find integral of Abel transform that describes
$$\int_y^\infty \frac{f(r)rdr}{(r^2 - y^2)}$$
where $f(r) = r^{-n}$ ? O have no idea at all, but the answer should be $\frac{k}{r^{-n+1}}$ where $k$ is a constant

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget that we have a nice geometric interpretation of the Able transformation: axially symmetric function projection along a line. So,
$$\frac{1}{\sin {\phi}} = \frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2-y^2}}$$
$$ F(r)=\int_{y}^{\infty} \frac{f(r)}{\sin{\phi}} \,dr = \frac{1}{\sin{\phi}} \int_{y}^{\infty} f(r)  \,dr$$
If $f(r)=r^{-n}$:
$$F(r)=\frac{r^{-n+1}}{\sin{\phi}}\Biggr|_{y}^{\infty}=\frac{y^{-n+1}}{\sin{\phi}}$$